# Install sqlite3 for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, sqlite, visual-studio-code

I am starting to build Ruby on Rails project, but can't start the server, because sqlite3 is not installed

> `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError).

I downloaded Precompiled Binaries for Windows archive from the sqlite site, where do I save the files now? What should I type in the terminal window?

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` in the console before stating rails server?

Comment: yes. the error is still there. I just dont know where do i place the sql files?

Comment: I would skip SQLite altogether and instead go straight to the DB you are going to use in production such as Postgres (SQLite is not really a good choice for a web server). Developing on a different database will sooner or later result in errors slipping into production. You can find [docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) that are pre-installed with everything you need which will also spare you a lot of the pain of trying to get things to work on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way i got to install sqlite3 is by running RailsInstaller (http://railsinstaller.org/en). It installs the whole bundle of programs for Ruby on Rails app though.

Answer (score 1):

To use sqlite3,

1. Unpack the precompiled Binaries for Windows in C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder.
2. Then on your cmd, do a "`gem install sqlite3`".

[That should fix it. To test:]

3. Create a rails app. "`rails new test`"
4. cd into the directory and "`rails g scaffold post title:string body:text`"
5. "`rails db:migrate`"

Comment: Nope. 
I placed the files into system32 directory, tried to run the server again, and it still gives me the same error

Comment: For my installation on windows, I used a rails installer, and so you'll find my sqlite3.dll & sqlite3.def in C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.3.3\bin. You might also want to check your variable path to see if system32 or ruby2.x.x/bin has been added